# Google Map distance calculation between multiple points

Tags: google-maps

I am calculating the distance and duration between an origin (say A) and a destination (say B) in Java using Google Map API as follows:-

```
DistanceMatrixApiRequest request = DistanceMatrixApi.newRequest(context).origins(origin).destinations(destination);
DistanceMatrix result = request.await();
System.out.println("Distance : "+result.rows[0].elements[0].distance.inMeters);
System.out.println("Duration : "+result.rows[0].elements[0].duration.humanReadable);
```

However if I want to calculate the duration and distance between multiple points (say A --> B --> C --> D), how do I do this? Should I repeat the above code between each of the points or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Is this for Android?  If not, what library/API are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in a single request:

- origins: [A,B,C]
- destinations: [B,C,D]

Then ignore the results you don't need (you only need A->B, B->C, C->D; not the other combinations).

Comment: That worked :)
However I have another question related to this. It allows only 10 origins and 10 destinations. Any inputs on how this can be fixed?